# PHP - Change value of variable in buffer

Tags: php, buffer

I want to change value of variable that was called before but should be changed after it. Like in this exapmle:

```
<img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" />
$src = 'some_src.jpg';
```

Maybe some kind of buffering or something? That should be done this way, cause I'm trying to make a kind of template engine:

```
$this->showHeader();
$this->showBody();
```

But the body is in another file. In this file i would call:

```
$this->header->setScript('somescript.js');
```

And that should change variables in header. But I can't call showBody() function before showHeader(). Sorry for my english. :(

Comment: That's a violation of causality. The variable is substituted at the time the first statement is executed, it's not a template that gets filled in later.

Comment: Why do you need to call a variable before its declared?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a variable after you call it. You will want to look at writing this in a different way like adding it a function attribute or some method of setting it properly before echoing it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way to do this. Buffering was the way to accomplish my task.

I couldn,t echo body of page before the head, but I had to call body before head to collect possible variables changes. So I've put the content of body to a buffer:

```
ob_start();
$this->showBody();
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

Now I've collected variables values and I could use them:

```
$this->showHeader();
echo $content;
```

Pretty simple.